# Adding a variable to kivy atlas file

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any way to add a variable to the `atlas` file in Kivy? I currently have this image [image]

and in my atlas file I have every frame listed. What I would prefer to have is a variable in the `y` location which I can then change from the `py` file inside the class.

So essentially my atlas would be this

```
{
    "frames/player.png": {
        "f0_1": [0, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_2": [64, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_3": [128, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_4": [192, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_5": [256, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_6": [320, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_7": [384, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_8": [448, var, 64, 50],
        "f0_9": [512, var, 64, 50]
    }
}
```

and I can change `var` in the `py` file based on which arrow key I press.

Current atlas file

```
{
    "frames/player.png": {
        "f0_1": [0, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_2": [64, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_3": [128, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_4": [192, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_5": [256, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_6": [320, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_7": [384, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_8": [448, 0, 64, 50],
        "f0_9": [512, 0, 64, 50],

        "f1_1": [0, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_2": [64, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_3": [128, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_4": [192, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_5": [256, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_6": [320, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_7": [384, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_8": [448, 50, 64, 50],
        "f1_9": [512, 50, 64, 50],

        "f2_1": [0, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_2": [64, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_3": [128, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_4": [192, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_5": [256, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_6": [320, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_7": [384, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_8": [448, 101, 64, 50],
        "f2_9": [512, 101, 64, 50],

        "f3_1": [0, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_2": [64, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_3": [128, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_4": [192, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_5": [256, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_6": [320, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_7": [384, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_8": [448, 150, 64, 50],
        "f3_9": [512, 150, 64, 50]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but keep in mind that the `.atlas` file must agree with the contents of the image file. If you just change the coordinates in the `.atlas` file, you will not get correct images when you use it.

Comment: @JohnAnderson My goal is to simplify my atlas and make it shorter. So looking at my image if I press the right arrow then the `y` value would be set to `0` which would use the bottom row of frames where the guy is walking right. If a press the `up` arrow then the `y` value gets changed to `150` which would then use the row of frames where the guy it walking upwards. The way my image is laid out the `x`, `width`, and `height` of each frame stay the same so I only need to change the `y` value.

Comment: You could create 4 `.atlas` files, each with a different `y` value, and just switch which `.atlas` file you are using based on your up/down arrows. I suspect that anything you do to `simplify` the `.atlas` file will overly complicate your usage of that file.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I'm not sure that would be any different (probably more complicated) than just one file. I have updated my post to show my current file which works fine. I just though I could shorten it up with a variable. I don't think it possible now though.